# Composite Pattern Entities with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, composite

Consider the following situation:
I am using a composite pattern for a structure which I want to grab by the root out of the database and which implements a "cascade interface", the cascade function is a function which is executed at the top but starts at the leafs of my composite tree, while the childreen always give the current solution too the parents. The leafs implement the interface in a different way than the nodes.

```
@Entity
public class Node implements Cascadable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany
  private List<Cascadable> children;
}
```

Obviously, this does not work, since I am giving this Entity and Attribut which is an Interface and an Interface can not be an entity. I could turn the interface into an abstract class, make an Entity out of it and either use @Inheritance or @MappedSuperclass with it, though in this case, I would not be able to extend this new abstract class with my leafs of this tree, since they use an ID which is not generated. Are there any alternatives to my approach? Optimal would be something like using multiple targetentities for the children attribute or something like that. If it is somehow possible to seperate the Leafs from the rest of the tree while still making it possible that the Nodes know which Leafs it contains, this would be another possible alternative.

Problem: Saving a hierachial structure in a DB, every node needs to know it's childreen, the leafs work different from the rest of the other nodes.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: years back i was doing something similar, we used `MappedSuperclass` for base node properties.

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure: this will never work with interfaces. Multiple unrelated entities, each with a separate table, may implement `Cascadable` and JPA needs to know which physical tables to apply constraints to. For the same reason, multiple association targets are not allowed.

> If it is somehow possible to seperate the Leafs from the rest of the tree

Well, the solution to that problem is the usual: favour composition over inheritance. Sounds like a good use case for the *bridge* pattern, you could represent the action to be executed in the form of an 'intelligent' enum, for example. Alternatively, depending on the exact use case, the *visitor* pattern could work as well.